# Cloudinary::CarrierWave how to select the upload folder in Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

I try to use the module `Cloudinary::CarrierWave`, but all my images are stored in the root folder of the cloud.

I want all my files to go to a specific remote folder.

I try this in my class:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
    def storage_identifier
        'specific_folder'
    end
end
```

I know there is some options with `Cloudinary::Upload.upload`, but as I use simple form in ruby on rails, I don't have access to this method.

Does anybody has an idea to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

When using Carrierwave with server-side uploads, you can use a code like the following:

```
classPictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base      
include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
 ...

  def public_id
    return "my_folder/" + model.short_name
   end  
 end
```

If you're using client-side upload, you can set the folder parameter when building the upload tag:

`<%= f.cl_image_upload(:image, :folder => "my_folder") %>`

Answer (score 0):

thanks to your answer, I solve that with your help, and I can give some other tips.

I did something like this to separate folders, but sometimes model.id doesn't exist (I should add an if else)

```
def public_id
  "artpieces/#{model.class}/#{model.id}"
end
```

This code doesn't work for me :

```
<%= f.cl_image_upload(:image, :folder => "my_folder") %>
```

I can write directly :

```
<%= f.input :photo, input_html: {accept: ('image') } %>
```

as my input is already a PhotoUploader declare like this in the model :

```
mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
```